# apply threshold on column values in a pysaprk dataframe and convert the values to binary 0 or 1

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, threshold

I have a PySpark dataframe

```
simpleData = [("person0",10, 10), \
    ("person1",1, 1), \
    ("person2",1, 0), \
    ("person3",5, 1), \
  ]
columns= ["persons_name","A", 'B']
exp = spark.createDataFrame(data = simpleData, schema = columns)

exp.printSchema()
exp.show()
```

It looks like

```
root
 |-- persons_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- A: long (nullable = true)
 |-- B: long (nullable = true)
 |-- total: long (nullable = true)

+------------+---+---+
|persons_name|  A|  B|
+------------+---+---+
|     person0| 10| 10|
|     person1|  1|  1|   
|     person2|  1|  0|    
|     person3|  5|  1|    
+------------+---+---+
```

Now I want a threshold of value 2 to be applied to the values of columns A and B, such that any value in the column less than the threshold becomes 0 and the values greater than the threshold becomes 1.

The final result should look something like-

```
+------------+---+---+
|persons_name|  A|  B|
+------------+---+---+
|     person0|  1|  1|
|     person1|  0|  0|   
|     person2|  0|  0|    
|     person3|  1|  0|    
+------------+---+---+
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
threshold = 2
exp.select(
    [(F.col(col) > F.lit(threshold)).cast('int').alias(col) for col in ['A', 'B']]
)
```